# SAP Web Intelligence Sum Product

Tags: sum, formula, webi

I have a problem generating a forecast. I have different projects with different planned and actual data.

In one report I want to show the projects in each line and in another report I want to show the aggregated overall result of all projects.

I tried:

```
=sum([FORECAST COST]) in ([Project])

=sum([FORECAST COST]] foreach ([Project])

=runningsum([FORECAST COST)] foreach ([Project])
```

[image: this is a example what the problem is about]

any idea?

Comment: Is **FORECAST COST** a dimension or measure?

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula in **Forecast cost** column:

```
=If [FORECAST COST] InList ("project a";"project b";"project c";"project d";"project e") Then "Sum" Else [FORECAST COST]
```

This applies to BO4.0. If you have 4.1 and higher, you can use [grouping](https://www.aits.uillinois.edu/UserFiles/Servers/Server_474/File/DS/Business%20Objects/Grouping%20Values%20in%20Web%20Intelligence%204.pdf).